# How to define transfinite derivatives of a function?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, real-analysis, fractional-calculus

There are all manners of theories [generalizing the notion of derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative). Amongst them is the [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), a rich theory which gives a sense to the derivation and integration of non-integer (i.e. rational, real, complex) order, that are the real/complex number powers of the differentiation ($D$) and integration ($J$) operators:

$Df(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

$Jf(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx$

Along these lines, one may think about *transfinite iteration* of $D$ and $J$ as well. While $D^{(n)}$ and $J^{(n)}$ are quite well-defined and well-behaved operators for the natural number $n$, I haven't found any convenient definition of $D^{(\alpha)}$ or $J^{(\alpha)}$ for the ordinal $\alpha\geq \omega$ in the literature if there is any.

Due to the similarity between natural and ordinal numbers, it seems the only difficulty is to formulate a definition of the differentiation operator in the *limit* steps like $D^{\omega}$ or $D^{\omega+\omega}$. One straightforward (but not necessarily well-defined, natural or fruitful) way to do so is to think about $D^{\omega}$ as a functional limit of $D^{n}$s in a certain function space. Though, I am not sure if it is the most clever approach. Anyway, it is somehow "natural" to expect that any $D^{\omega}$ operator demonstrates certain properties like: $D^{\omega}x^{n}=0$ for every $n\in \omega$.

Also, the spaces of smooth and analytic functions, $C^{\infty}$ and $C^{\omega}$, don't seem to capture the essence of the very notion of the *$\omega$-the derivative* of a function, particularly because they don't suggest a clear way of calculating transfinite successor differentiation operators, $D^{\omega+1}$, $D^{\omega+2}$, $D^{\omega+3}$, etc.

> **Question.** Is there any paper in which transfinite derivatives of (real/complex) functions are defined/used? If so, what sort of applications do they have?

---

**Update.** Due to the answer that Andrés mentioned in [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303660/how-to-define-transfinite-derivatives-of-a-function#comment756892_303660), it turned out that defining $D^{\omega}$ operator as the limit of $D^{n}$s gives rise to a trivial notion. So maybe a more *direct* approach is needed here.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/595318/462).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo (+1) Oh interesting! Let me check your answer over there! Thank you, Andrés! :-)

Comment: @Somos Your question is actually an *axiomatic version* of my original question here in this post. So I am not sure because that is the essence of this "*How to define...?*" question! Anyway, one's set of *expectations* from $D^{\omega}$ may vary depending on their personal intuition and background.  Maybe one finds it plausible to have $D^{\omega}e^{x}=0$ or $1$. Somebody else may bring set-theoretic assumptions about properties of $\mathbb{R}$ into the play and make the question of calculating infinite derivation of certain functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ independent of $ZFC$!

Comment: Your question may make more sense in a field of Conway's surreal numbers. Have a look at the preprint Surreal numbers, derivations and transseries by Alessandro Berarducci, Vincenzo Mantova, https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00315.

Comment: @DávidNatingga (+1) Really interesting, David! Why not posting it as an answer to this reference request question? Not to mention that the natural follow-up that I had in mind for this question has been combining the transfinite and fractional derivations in order to approach the notion of the derivation of surreal number order.

Comment: I don't see how the paper of Berarducci and Mantova answers this question.

Comment: I second nombre's sentiment, and I would bet money that there is a robust answer to this question somewhere over the surreals.  For a starter to address an issue brought up in the comments on Andrés's other answer, $a^\alpha e^{ax}$ is trivially well defined in $N_0$ for all $\alpha\in O_n$ and $a\in N_0$.

Comment: @MortezaAzad Sorry, I think this question is quite important and deserves a better answer than I could give at this time.

Comment: @DávidNatingga (+1) Thanks for your contribution, David! Please feel free to add an answer or email me if you come up with any (even partial) answer to this question! I am really interested in hearing more about it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a such a notion of transfinite derivative, I don't think it will be very robust. Here's the problem I see with indexing repeated differentiation with ordinals. We would almost certainly want the following natural property: $$D^{\beta} \circ D^{\alpha} = D^{\alpha+\beta}$$.

This would give us, for example, that $$D^{\omega} \circ D = D^{1+\omega} = D^{\omega}$$ and $$D \circ D^{\omega} = D^{\omega+1}$$ But now let's try some of the nicest analytic functions we have: $sin(t)$ and $cos(t)$. We should expect $D^{\omega}sin(t) = sin(t)$ and $D^{\omega}cos(t) = cos(t)$, since the ordinal $\omega$ is "0 (mod 4)", if anything. But then $$sin(t) = D^{\omega}sin(t) = (D^{\omega} \circ D)sin(t) = D^{\omega}cos(t) = cos(t)$$ which is a problem.

To make this objection more precise: what is the largest "natural class" of functions $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ for which we can define transfinite derivatives? Let's assume that by "natural class", we mean it is a collection of functions closed under scaling, addition of functions, and composition of functions. Then there is no natural class $\mathcal{A}$ containing both $e^t$ and all polynomials for which we can make a reasonable definition of transfinite derivative. Why? Because if $e^t, it \in \mathcal{A}$, then $cos(t) = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} \in \mathcal{A}$ and $sin(t) = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} \in \mathcal{A}$, and we have already argued there is no reasonable way to define the $\omega$-th derivative of $sin(t)$ and $cos(t)$.

---

Here's a rough sketch of an idea using non-standard analysis (as motivated by Dávid Natingga's comment):

There probably is a reasonable notion of taking "non-standardly" many derivatives, however. One way of thinking about this is to start with a (standard) analytic function $f$ whose Taylor coefficients are form a nice definable sequence (like $a_n = \frac{1}{n!}$) which decays sufficiently quickly. Then for a non-standard natural number N, we can look at the non-stanard polynomial $p_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n$. If we plug in a standard real number $r$ into $p_N(x)$ and take the standard part, we will just get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n r^n = f(r)$, roughly because the terms $a_M r^M$ for M non-standard are infinitessimal.

Now let $M$ be some non-standard natural number (here we imagine N is much bigger than M), we can certainly define $p_{N}^{(M)}(x) = D^{M}\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n$. Keeping $M$ fixed, as long as $N$ is big enough, the standard part of $p^{(M)}_N(r)$ for $r$ a standard real number does not depend on $N$. So we can define $f{(M)}(r) = p_N^{(M)}(r)$ for any $N$ sufficiently big. This gives us a well-defined notion of of the $M$-th derivative $f^{(M)}$ of a function $f$ with a "nice" Taylor series.

(**Caveat**: I don't really do non-standard analysis, so there may be some conceptual errors here)

Comment: This argument fails if we use natural addition in the definition of $D^\beta\circ D^\alpha=D^{\beta+\alpha}$ since $1+\omega=\omega+1\neq\omega$, which seems the natural choice to me. I think the main problem you are illuminating here is that noncommutative binary operations don't generalize well to operators indexed over that set if we want the induced operator addition to be commutative, which is fixed by choosing a commutative binary operation to begin with.

Comment: Speaking as a physicist, you can "regulate" $D^\omega \sin t$ by instead considering $D^\omega \sin \lambda t$. While not defined for $\lambda = 1$, for all $|\lambda| <1$ there is no difficulty in defining $D^\omega \sin \lambda t = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} D^n \sin\lambda t = 0$. For $|\lambda| > 1$ it is less well-behaved but can be considered as (complex) $\infty$ (there is some difficulty at integral multiples of $\pi/2$ but if more general perturbations are allowed this can be dealt with). I would not call this "robust" but it shows that your example is perhaps a degenerate case.

Comment: @AlecRhea: If you have $D^{\beta} \circ D^{\alpha} = D^{\beta+\alpha}$, then $D^{\omega} f = D^{1+\omega}f=D(D^{\omega}f)$ and so the $\omega$-th derivatives have to be of the form $Ce^x$. I think James' choice is the correct one since $\alpha+\beta$ in ordinal arithmetic means "apply $\beta$-many successors after $\alpha$-many times", so $D^{\alpha+\beta}$ should mean "differentiate $\beta$-many times after $\alpha$-many times".

Comment: "(...) since the ordinal $\omega$ is $0(\mathrm{mod}4)$, if anything" - Really? Why?

Comment: @Burak: It is certainly a matter of definition what type of algebraic relation should the transfinite iterations of the differential operator satisfy. For instance, the iterated integration should satisfy properties dual to that of the iterated differentiation, so at least one of those will be at odds with your common sense argument. (And I think Alec Rhea was refering to Hessenberg arithmetic, i.e. natural arithmetic)

Comment: @Qfwfq I am using (a generalization of) this notion: [Even and Odd Ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_ordinals)

Or, if you think this is cheating/verbal trickery, you can check each of the four "obvious" possibilities sin(t), cos(t), -sin(t), and -cos(t), and find an inconsistency.

The only somewhat reasonable answer is 0 as Logan M suggested (which happens to be the average of these four possibilities), but this kind of reasoning would also lead us to think $D^{\omega}e^t = 0$ as well, which most people would reject.

Comment: @James: oh I see, I was not aware of parity of ordinals

Comment: @Burak Just to be clear, the relation $\omega=1+\omega$ does **not** hold if we interpret $+$ as the natural sum of ordinals instead of the recursive sum, which is what I am suggesting we should do. I do think that derivative operators indexed in the Grothendieck ring of the ordinals are more likely to satisfy nice duality properties with integration, since we always have successors in both directions.

Comment: @AlecRhea To elaborate a little more, Hessenberg natural sum and product on ordinals are commutative, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations.